# Why does the led turn on in the following circuit?

Tags: transistors, current, diodes, npn, pnp

So i have connected a transistor as shown below where the base of the transistor is connected to the negative of the power source and the emitter is connected to the negative  side of an led and the collector is not connected anywhere but how does current flow from the base to the Emitter btw this is a bc537

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PirFy.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PirFy.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOzb3.jpg)[image]

Comment: It's a PNP transistor and you wired it up as a diode, which is forward biased so of course it conducts.

Comment: You say the transistor is a BC537 which is an NPN, but your schematic shows a PNP. Which is correct? Did the LED light up?

Comment: You are correct I made a mistake it is actually an npn transistor

Comment: Can you redraw your circuit showing the NPN connection?

Answer (score 2):

Let's draw your circuit the right way up. Positive to top, negative to bottom. Current flows from top to bottom.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f60t7F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Your circuit. (b) The equivalent circuit.*

The PNP transistor in this configuration behaves like two diodes with common cathodes. Current simply flows through D1 (lighting it), Q1 (D3) and R1.

You'll lose about 0.6 or 0.7 V across the emitter-base junction of the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

The emitter-base junction is a PN junction in some respects very similar to a diode and you are forward-biasing it.

Answer (score 0):

The  B-E junction is basically a diode so the expected result is that the LED lights up.